# .NET Event when laptop is going into suspend mode?

Tags: .net

Is there anyway to get a handle to when a laptop is going into suspend mode and do something before it actually goes into suspend mode?

I assume this is not easy/possible because it would be ill-advised for the power management to honor any such software that was trying to stop it from going into suspend mode.

The specific use is to have a tray app notify fogbugz to stop work when I close my laptop lid.

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx